# loop thru all edittext views in activity

Tags: java, android-edittext

I am creating a quote program where the user enters values into edittext views , I need to validate all the textviews have a value. I can find each textview with

```
 edittext1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.Layout.etEditText1)
```

I would like to loop thru all the edittext views with out using a bunch of if statements.is there a foreach loop or for loop that I can use here?

I have a c# sharp background and am new to Java...any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add all editTexts to an array or a list:

```
EditText[] ets = new EditText[nbr];
ets[0] = edittext1;
ets[1] = edittext1;
....
```

and then loop over them with:

```
for (EditText et : ets) {
  if (!et.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: this is a good solution, but I was hoping there was a way to find each edit text view without hard coding them in....is there a way to find all the edit text by id in a loop? I read about the method getChildCount() but I get errors "cannot resolve" when I try to use it.

Comment: I decided to use this answer because I couldn't get the other answers to work!

Answer (score 0):

```
TableLayout tView = (TableLayout) findViewById (R.id.table_layout);
        for(int i=0; i<((ViewGroup)tView).getChildCount(); ++i) {
            View someView = ((ViewGroup)tView).getChildAt(i);
            if(someView instanceof EditText){
               //Your logic
            }

        }
```

Comment: You don't know android programming? I have states "v" should be your root view

Comment: it wont let me post all the xml..says its to long

Comment: TableLayout v;
                v = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_layout);
                for(int i= 0; i < v.getChildCount(); ++i) 
                {
                    View someView = v.getChildAt(i);
                    if(someView instanceof EditText){

                        if (someView.equals(""))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "View is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                }

Comment: table layout is the root layout

Comment: what do you mean by that ?

Comment: I add this code and in the if(someView instanceof EditText) statement I add a toast...the toast never shows even when the edittext fields are empty!

Comment: do you have table rows ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67226/discussion-between-suncoastowner-and-murtaza-hussain).